# Azure website returning 404 on PHP pages

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

My azure website is always responding 404 for .php file.

The HTML (.html) and Plain text (.txt) are working fine.

We tried to add a phpinfo.php with :

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

and the server is responding 404.

We also add a phpinfo.html, with only text inside and the server is returning the good page.

We have activated the application logging (File system) and we can see an error : SECURITY_DENIED_BY_MIMEMAP.  But can't find anything with this for php file. There are alot of example with static content (.woff, .svg,..) but nothing with .PHP...

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4668021-b29f-4b46-98ac-72993d324ac8/after-i-deploy-a-php-application-to-windows-azure-i-get-a-404-error-when-i-try-to-access-my?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

Comment: The site was working yesterday (The site is up since November 2013).  We didn't deploy anything on it since February...  So my guess is that PHP is correctly installed on the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the problem.

For a reason we don't know. Our site was now in PHP 5.5.  We put it back in PHP 5.4 and everything is working fine.

Don't know why when we are in PHP 5.5 every .php can't be load but at least we fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Weird as I've got PHP apps running on Azure in PHP 5.5.

Just created the phpinfo() as you described (See [github.com/DragonBe/testphp55](https://github.com/DragonBe/testphp55)) and hooked it into Azure Websites using the repo importer.

I flipped the PHP version from 5.4 to 5.5.

[image: Configure php 5.5]

And checked out the website [testphp55.azurewebsites.net](http://testphp55.azurewebsites.net) with success.

[image: Running php 5.5.14]

So, if it's not working for you with PHP 5.5 I wonder what you've done different.

Comment: I used a FTP connection to send my phpinfo file, but i know I put it at the right place beacause my .txt ans .html are alose there and working.  I really can't tell you what's different...  I will make some tests later and keep you up. Thanks.